# Angular2 delay to update view

Tags: angular, typescript

I've noticed a weird behaviour with my components using Angular 2.
My views take few seconds to be updated once my component changes the model included as my providers. Even if the data from the API is a single data.

For example:

I have as my provider the model called UserModel
Inside my component I get data from API and then update this model which is also inside my view.
After getting the response from server, it still takes few seconds to update my view, and sometimes it doesn't update, just after I click on any text controller on the same page and then my view is updated after any text gets focus.

Has anyone already seen this ? What could I be doing wrong ?

Card Component

```
public createCard(model:CardModel):Promise<any>{
    var context = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.stripe.createToken(model)
        .then(function(token){
            model.token = token;
            context.saveCard("./card", model, true)
                    .then(data => resolve(data))
                    .catch(error => reject(error));
        })
        .catch(error => reject(error));
});
```

Stripe Service

```
public createToken(model:CardModel):Promise<any>{
    //I get callback and convert return it as promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            //this function is the one from stripe.js, it is not promise
            this.stripe.card.createToken(model, function(status, response){
            if(status == 200){
                resolve(response.id);
            }else{
                reject(response.error.message);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If you notice the function createToken returns as callback because it is a Strip.js function, and then I convert it to Promise to return it to createCard. But once all functions are completed my zone is not changed. If I remove this.stripe.card.createToken and return a simple resolve() using timeout, it works fine. So I believe the issue is when have a async function returning callback inside a Promise. But I have no clue how to deal with it.

Comment: This is usually when some code that runs outside Angulars zone updates the data. Some APIs with callbacks that aren't patched by Angulars zone can cause this. In this case Angular doesn't know it needs to run change detection. I would need to see some code.

Comment: I've updated the question adding some code

Comment: `Promise` might depend on some polyfill loading order. If you use Observable it should definitely work. Besides that there is nothing supsicious.

Comment: I was suspecting something like that, but I use observables inside my service just before returning to my component, do u reckon that even treating my data as observable inside my service and returning as promise to my component could be an issue ? I'll give a try on it.

Comment: I remember seeing it mentioned that `Promise` might cause this (not experienced myself). I don't see anything else that might cause this issue.

Comment: I recently ran into an issue where a third-party library included some of the polyfills that it depended on. Loading that library after zone.js was loaded caused things like Promise to be overwritten, preventing Angular from picking up on changes.

Comment: Based on the comments above and after digging some functions I noticed that the issue is related to functions which return promise based on callbacks. But I still don't know how to deal with this, I'm updating the code to clarify what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using a third party library that does not work well with Angular 2. I had the same issue with StripeJS. The issue is related to Angular's Zone.js and Lifecycle - it's very similar to that bad digest cycle issue in Angular 1. Angular has detailed documentation on the solution here: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#example-live-demo

In order to solve it, you have to implement your own lifecycle loop and add your third party library into the change detection. 
My implementation for StripeJS (also remember to destroy the setInterval with clearInterval:

```js
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  AfterContentInit,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ViewContainerRef,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'v-payment-form', // <payment-form></payment-form>
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './payment-form.component.html'
})
export class PaymentFormComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
  checker: any;
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.checker = setInterval(() => {
      // the following is required, otherwise the view will not be updated
      this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }, 75);
  }
  addPaymentMethod() {
    Stripe.card.createToken(cardDetails)
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // ..load stripe js here - I use scriptjs 
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    clearInterval(this.checker)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been several years since this issue is posted here, but I had a similar problem recently because my promises were running "outside" Angular.

As mentioned in a comment this is similar to the digest cycle issue in Angular 1 where to "force" Angular to recognize anything it wasn't "seeing" we used $scope.$apply()

In Angular 2 NgZone solves these problems. It is defined by the documentation as: "An injectable service for executing work inside or outside of the Angular zone.": [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

So to solve the problem it is necessary to ensure that the code runs by calling ngZone like this:

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    // some async code here
});
```

You need import NgZone from @angular/core and add it on the constructor:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
    // some code here
}
```

So, the code in this 5 years old question can be like this: (notice the "this.ngZone.run" inside the Promises)

```
public createCard(model:CardModel):Promise<any>{
    var context = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.stripe.createToken(model).then(function(token) {
                model.token = token;
                context.saveCard("./card", model, true)
                    .then(data => resolve(data))
                    .catch(error => reject(error));
            })
            .catch(error => reject(error));
        });
    });
}


public createToken(model:CardModel):Promise<any>{
    //I get callback and convert return it as promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            //this function is the one from stripe.js, it is not promise
            this.stripe.card.createToken(model, function(status, response){
                if(status == 200){
                    resolve(response.id);
                }else{
                    reject(response.error.message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

But I would prefer to refactor those Promises and use async/await and make it look more like this to use a single ngZone.run call:

```
createAndSaveCard() {
    this.ngZone.run(async() => {
        const token = await createToken();
        const card = await createCard(token);
        await this.saveCard();
    });
}
```